# loading raw file from github in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load a codebook from github in R studio. The url is [here][1]. It is a `md` file based on the link, but I want to load its raw file. (As `pic1` shows on the top right this is a tab called `raw`, and when I click that, it shows `pic2`).I try to use the link provided, but it does not work. Could anyone help to tell how to do that? Thanks a lot!

```
cddf<-url("https://github.com/HimesGroup/BMIN503/blob/master/DataFiles/NHANES_2007to2008_DataDictionary.md")
cd<-read.table(cddf )
```

Update:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
When I changed the code :

```
codebook<-read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HimesGroup/BMIN503/master/DataFiles/NHANES_2007to2008_DataDictionary.md",skip = 4, sep = "|", head = TRUE)
```

The r successfully read most of them, but the sep "|" did not work for two variables: INDHHIN2 and MCQ010. See pic. Can anyone help to figure out why? Thanks~~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, the raw file is available at the link `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HimesGroup/BMIN503/master/DataFiles/NHANES_2007to2008_DataDictionary.md`.  However, `read.table` is not going to be able to read that file without some help:  `read.table` is used for tab or comma delimited files, and that's a table marked up for Markdown.  This comes close:

```
read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HimesGroup/BMIN503/master/DataFiles/NHANES_2007to2008_DataDictionary.md",
 skip = 4, sep = "|", head = TRUE)
```

but it will still need some cleanup, to remove the first and last columns of junk it added, and to delete the first line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @user2554330. Only one question that when I use the code to read the file, 2 out 13 variables are failed to be separated by "|". one is INDHHIN2, another is MCQ010. And dataset shows it only has 11 total rows which should be 13 rows (1 row need to be removed and 12 variables in dataset). Could plz help to see why this happens? Thanks a lot~~!

Comment: I think you will need to download the file and clean it up.  `read.table` isn't really up to the job on a messy table like that.  It needs some human intelligence to fix all the inconsistencies.  I'd do the cleanup in a spreadsheet and save it in CSV format, so `read.csv` can read it.